# cocos2d game develop

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i am new to cocos2d technology. I want to develop game. I need some idea about level of difficulty. Also i want to know about project type whether this game need to be develop in CoCos2d BOX2d application or simple cocos2d application.

This is game link : http://www.mindjolt.com/games/super-balance

Please provide me guidance for the same..!

Waiting for reply

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Box2D and create a 2D gravity world (that is the part where you need Box2D). then learn Box2D from Ray ( http://www.raywenderlich.com/475/how-to-create-a-simple-breakout-game-with-box2d-and-cocos2d-tutorial-part-12 ).

learn Box2D and you will see how to implement it into this game ;)